# Container db1479aa5900ccb7acb83db7e3f4f1a5351f4ab1609edca36e41cb01a39d9e0e is not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have my docker-compose.yml with this code i have added 2 services. This successfully build with `docker-compose up -d --build`

```
version: "2"

services:
  expo:
    build:
      context: ./dev
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: sis-expo
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      #- EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ADB_IP=192.168.1.1
      - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.33
    expose:
      - "19000"
      - "19001"
      - "19002"
    ports:
      - 19000:19000
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
    tty: true

  firebase:
    build:
      context: ./dev
      dockerfile: firebase.dockerfile
    container_name: sis-expo-firebase
    ports:
      - 4000:4000 # Emulator Suite UI
      - 5000:5000 # Firebase Hosting
      - 5001:5001 # Clound Functions
      - 9000:9000 # Realtime Database
      - 8080:8080 # Cloud Firestore
      - 8085:8085 # Cloud Pub/Sub
      - 9005:9005
    command: "echo this is a test"
```

then run `docker-compose up -d` to start container then i check with `docker ps` but the container isn't there then i tried to do `docker ps -a` it show container exited.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS                                                                   NAMES
511c3cf9163c   sis-mobile_firebase           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Exited (0) 11 seconds ago                                                                           sis-expo-firebase
```

And its logs can be viewed with `docker logs <id>`.

```
this is a test
```

Please let me know if you need further information. Not sure if this is enough to truly solve my problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: `docker` commands don't normally write out PNG files; is there plain-text output from `docker ps`?  If the container isn't running, is there information in its logs saying why it exited?  What's in the relevant Dockerfile?  Is the other container required to reproduce the issue?  (Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?)

Comment: With the final `command:` I'd expect the container to just print out `this is a test` and then exit immediately, which matches what you're seeing.  Does deleting that `command:` line help?  It should use the Dockerfile's `CMD` line, which should hopefully start the service.

Comment: I added line ```tty: true``` and remove ```command``` now i can see the container in ```docker ps```.